# How can I copy cell fill color from one document to another?

Tags: openpyxl

I am attempting to open one file, see if cells have color fills, and copy the coordinate and fill information to a dictionary. Then, I want to iterate over the dictionary to copy the formatting into the same coordinates in a different document. (This may not be the best way to accomplish this)

```
def color_collect(wb):  # This collects colors from cell coordinates
    color_data = OrderedDict()
    for sheetcount, wksht in enumerate(wb.worksheets):
        color_data[sheetcount] = {}
        for row in wksht:
            for cell in row:
                coord = cell.coordinate
                coordcolor = cell.fill.start_color.index
                if coordcolor != '00000000':
                    color_data[sheetcount][coord] = coordcolor
    return color_data


def color_write(wb, color_data):  # This adds color to cell coordinates
    print color_data
    for idx, sheet in enumerate(wb):
        print idx
        for cell in color_data[idx]:
            print cell
            coloridx = color_data[idx][cell]
            print coloridx
            sheet[cell].fill.start_color.index = color_data[idx][cell]
```

Running this gives this result:

> sheet[cell].fill.start_color.index = color_data[idx][cell]
>
> AttributeError: can't set attribute

Some notes: the index color is crucial because I use the index color to import the color-coded data into PowerPoint. If the index isn't properly applied, the data is not recognized later, so solutions that use plain RGB fills aren't super useful.

Any assistance would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is best done by [copying styles](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html#copying-styles)

Something like `sheet[c1].fill = copy(c2.fill)`

Comment: So, to copy styles from one workbook to another, I'd have to read one workbook and open the other at the same time, copy styles, then save the copied Workbook?